# Join split words and punctuation correctly

Tags: python, list, join, split

So I have this list:

```
list1 = ['hi', 'there', '!', 'i', 'work', 'for', 'Spencer', '&', 'Co']
```

I want to join the list together and have some of the punctuation join to the words, but others not to:

I am currently using:

```
list1 = " ".join()

re.sub(r' (?=\W)', '', list1)
```

This makes every punctuation join to the previous element.

> hi there! i work for Spencer& Co

But
I want:

> hi there! i work for Spencer & Co

Comment: Just change `\W` to `[.?!,]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally avoid using regular expressions since pure logical solutions are more easy to understand to me. Here is a short solution you could use for your above example:

```
list1 = ['hi', 'there', '!', 'i', 'work', 'for', 'Spencer', '&', 'Co']
output = ""
for part in list1:
    output += " " + part + " "
output = [1:-1]
```

The last line removes the starting space character and the ending space character.

Comment: Hi. Could I help with my answer? If you liked it, you could set the check mark and upvote my answer if you want to. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negated character set with your look-ahead and include your special character(s):

```
>>> re.sub(r' (?=[^\w&])', '', list1) # include &
'hi there! i work for Spencer & Co'
```